# Which Layout Manager Should I use to achieve the following?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, miglayout, border-layout

I have a `JFrame` and three `JPanel`s. On the frame I used `BorderLayout`. At the `CENTER` of the frame I have put `outerPanel`. On my `outerPanel` I have used `MigLayout`. The two other panels are added on to the `outerPanel`. These two panels are of equal size and their widths add up  to the width of the `outerPanel` - **I wanted the** `outerPanel` **to be divided into two halves**. Below is the code for this:

```
public class ControlPanel extends JFrame {

// components

public JPanel outerPanel;
public JPanel innerPanel1;
public JPanel innerPanel2;

public ControlPanel() {
    this.createUI();
}

public void createUI() {
    // form properties
    this.setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(300, 300));
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

    this.outerPanel = new JPanel();
    this.outerPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(260, 250));
    this.outerPanel.setLayout(new net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout());
    this.outerPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

    this.add(new javax.swing.JLabel("North"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    this.add(this.outerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    this.innerPanel1 = new JPanel();
    this.innerPanel1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(130, 150));
    this.innerPanel1.setLayout(new net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout());
    this.innerPanel1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Panel1"));

    this.innerPanel2 = new JPanel();
    this.innerPanel2.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(130, 150));
    this.innerPanel2.setLayout(new net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout());
    this.innerPanel2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Panel2"));

    this.outerPanel.add(this.innerPanel1);
    this.outerPanel.add(this.innerPanel2);
    this.pack();

    }

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ControlPanel cp = new ControlPanel();
  }
}
```

**Problem**: When I run my program, the GUI that appears **before I resize the window** is fine; but **when I resize the window -enlarging it**, `innerPane1` and `innerPanel2` **remains of the same size without resizing to occupy the space available**.

**Question**: How do we make the two panels , `innerPannel1` and `innerPanel2`, resize at the same time with the window so that they can share equally the available space? Any particular Layout Manager that can be used to divide a panel into two equal halves that can resize at the same time with the window?

**Images Showing the output.**

1. Before resizing - the GUI looks well and the panels have correct size.

[image]

2. After resizing -the GUI is distorted and the panels doesn't change size.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you use `new GridLayout(1, 2)`. This will split the panel in 1 row and 2 (equally sized) columns.

So, simply changing

```
this.outerPanel = new JPanel();
```

to

```
this.outerPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
```

should do.

Comment: `new GridLayout(1, 2)` on the `outterPanel` or the `JFrame`?

Comment: It worked exactly the way I wanted. I will accept your solution.